# On Sobolev's inequality for weakly conformal maps

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, conformal-maps

Suppose $u\in W^{2,p}(B^2,\mathbb{R}^n)$, $1<p<2$, is weakly conformal, that is
$$|u_x|=|u_y|,\quad u_x\cdot u_y=0$$
for almost every $(x,y)\in B^2$. Here $B^2$ is the unit open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Does the following Sobolev's inequality holds:
\begin{equation}
\|\nabla u\|_{L^{\frac{2p}{2-p}}(B)}\leq C_p\|u\|_{W^{2,p}(B,\mathbb{R}^n)}
\end{equation}
with a constant $C_p$ does not blow up when $p\to 2$?

If $u$ is not assumed to be weakly conformal, then it is known that the constant $C_p$ will blow up as $p\to 2$ and I wonder under what kind of assumptions on the map $u$ could make the constant stay bounded as $p\to 2$. Any suggestions and comments are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Here you need probably either u=0 on the boundary of B, or, the integral mean of u vanishes on B, or on the left hand side of the Sobolev inequality, you shrik the domain B to half of it?